# GET list of Ids in a comma seperated string and use with a INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server

First I have to fetch List of Id's with a condition say

```
SELECT Id 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE Validity = 'Date' AND ExpiryDate < GETDATE();
```

Here I have to keep list of ids as a string example 1,2,3 or 44,56,67,77 etc

Then I have to run an update query

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET Status = 'Expired'  
WHERE Validity = 'Date' AND ExpiryDate < GETDATE();
```

Here I have to keep the record affected

Then I have to do an insert query where I have to use the list of ids and the no of records affected by UPDATE query and insert to a new table

```
INSERT INTO LicenseExpiryJobLog (Descr) 
VALUES ('Detected IDs= { here comma seperated ids} Total rows updated = ');
```

How can I get the 2 variables in the final insert in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in many way but here is my simple version.

```
DECLARE @IDs VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ROW_COUNT INT
DECLARE @STR_LOG VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @IDs = COALESCE(@IDs + ', ', '') + Id FROM TABLE1 WHERE Validity='Date' AND ExpiryDate < GETDATE();

UPDATE  TABLE1 SET Status=Éxpired  WHERE Validity='Date' AND ExpiryDate < GETDATE();

SELECT @ROW_COUNT = @@ROWCOUNT

SET @STR_LOG = 'Detected IDs= ' + @IDs + ' Total rows updated = ' + CAST(@ROW_COUNT AS VARCHAR(5)) + ''

INSERT INTO LicenseExpiryJobLog (Descr) VALUES (@STR_LOG);
```

Comment: I am getting Error converting data type varchar to bigint. on first line of sql

Comment: Try converting `Id` to `VARCHAR`, like this: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Id)`

Comment: Just want to know how can i handle o rows scenario . IN that case description turns NULL [if no values in @IDs variable  and UPdate records affected =0]

Comment: Try to handle Ids with is null check to make sure it doesn't  throw error ISNULL(Ids,''). ROW_COUNT is declared as a int so you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`OUPUT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (id INT)

UPDATE TABLE1 
    SET Status = 'Expired' 
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @ids
WHERE Validity = 'Date' AND ExpiryDate < GETDATE();

INSERT INTO LicenseExpiryJobLog (Descr)
SELECT
    'Detected IDS = {' + 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), id)
        FROM @ids
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') + '}'
    + ' Total Rows Updated = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COUNT(*))
FROM @ids
```